# Can i put an en-el14 in my Nikon camera instead of en-el14a?

Tags: nikon, battery

I have a Nikon D3300, however I only have one battery and want to buy a second one. Can I use an en-el14 in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please start with reading your camera's manual. As far as I can read, EN-EL14 (without the -a) is compatible:

[image: nikon d3300 battery]