# Can i use EN-EL14 instead of EN-EL14a?

Tags: nikon, battery

I have been looking for a new battery for my Nikon D3300. It says the battery i need is an EN-EL14a, can i use an EN-EL14 instead? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i put an en-el14 in my Nikon camera instead of en-el14a?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/88503/can-i-put-an-en-el14-in-my-nikon-camera-instead-of-en-el14a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either the EL14 or the EL14A. Be advised that the EL14A has slightly more capacity. In other words more shots per charge.